# drawing button in absulote position android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-imageview, android-button

I am trying to do an in door map, with buttons on it. I designed the map and i want to put the buttons on it as shown in this pic:

[image: In door map, with buttons in certain positions]

so when user click the buttons i will go to another activity.

My question is How to put the buttons at those absolute positions and let it work for all screen rosulotions?

I have no idea where to start from, just an idea or suggestions can save my day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion using *absolute* positions for those buttons is not a good practice, because handling different screen sizes would be really difficult. In the other side, in my opinion, using *percentage* positions could be a better solution. For example:

Button #1:

- Top: 20%
- Left: 35%

Button #2

- Top: 0%
- Left: 80%

If as such, you're okay with this way, you can start with a `FrameLayout` and use `LayoutParams` to apply left and top margins to the buttons. For example for button #1 you would write:

```
int frameWidth = frameLayout.getWidth();
int frameHeight = frameLayout.getHeight();    

Button button = new Button(context);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.leftMargin = frameWidth * (percentageLeft / 100);
p.topMargin = frameHeight * (percentageTop / 100);
button.setLayoutParams(params);

frameLayout.addView(button, p);
```

Comment: I changed the pic, now the middle button, is not exactly in the middle, it should be on the intersection between the lins, so it cant be represented by percentage, I may need to draw them on canvas

Comment: @MBH You probably need to position those lines also in percentage values, so you can now use percentage positions for all elements. Also note that all absolute positions can be divided by frame width and height to be represented in percentage value.

Answer (score 1):

You can set buttons position by using layout margin (left, right, top, bottom) OR use absolute layout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html).

Example :
http://sampleprogramz.com/android/absolutelayout.php

Also to maintain buttons position on other resolutions use dip/dp unit instead of px. 
Check this doc,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: It doesnt work for my situation, cuz buttons are placed according to the lines of the rectangles inside the pic

Answer (score 0):

This is code for open new activity:

```
public void onclick(){intent i = new intent(MainActivity.this,activity.class);
```

startActivity(i)}

This is code for button:

```
<Button
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left|top"
android:onClick="onclick"
/>
```

Comment: my question is not about how to start another activity, it is about how to place the buttons on exactly the place i want on the imageview or bitmap